# Secure file downloads on IIS 8 (mod_auth_token or similar)

Tags: php, iis, file-sharing, files

I'm trying to set up secure file downloads (for example, where a temporary link can be generated to download a file instead of using obscure URLs, which can be insecure). Something like mod_auth_token would work well, but we're using IIS 8 and I can't seem to find an equivalent.

We are using a custom token-based API authentication system for the site, and the file download link will be generated on demand by a PHP API and returned to the application via JSON.

What would be a good way to accomplish this in IIS?